# Check for resonance conditions - Pythonic/Algorithmic improvements?

Tags: python, algorithm

The purpose of this question is to improve my skills with python and/or algorithms.

I have two arrays (modes[:,2], modes[:,3]) and am trying to find out all the possible unique combinations where

```
modes[i,2]+modes[j,2] = modes[k,2] (within a numerical bound)
AND
modes[i,3]+modes[j,3] = modes[k,3] (within a numerical bound)
```

Right now I'm just using a simple triple nested loop to do this:

```
import numpy as np
# Load the array from file
modes=np.loadtxt('nonzeros.txt')
ebk=modes[:,4].max()
ofile=open('parametric_modes.txt','w')


for k in range(len(modes[:,0])):
   for i in range(len(modes[:,0])):
      for j in range(i+1,len(modes[:,0])):

         # Check for the resonance condition.
         if modes[k,2]-0.01 <= modes[i,2]+modes[j,2]\
             <=modes[k,2]+0.01 and modes[k,3]-0.01 <=\
          modes[i,3]+modes[j,3] <= modes[k,3]+0.01:

            # Check the amplitude.
            if modes[k,4] >= ebk*2e-3:

               print >> ofile,modes[i,4],modes[j,4],modes[k,4],\
                              modes[i,2],modes[j,2],modes[k,2],\
                              modes[i,3],modes[j,3],modes[k,3]

ofile.close()
```

But for obvious reasons, I am getting repetitions of the combinations. There should be a more elegant way of doing it (either algorithmic or pythonic). Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
l = len(modes[:,0])

[(i, j, k) for i in range(0, l) for i in range(0, l ) for j in range(i, l ) if (abs(modes[i,2]+modes[j,2] - modes[k,2]) + abs(modes[i,3]+modes[j,3] - modes[k,3])) < .01 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do O(n^2logn).

Sort the arrays. For every combination of i&j, do a binary search to get the closest k to match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve two instances of what amounts to the [3SUM Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM), for which Wikipedia has a straightforward O(N^2) algorithm. Tweaking it for your purposes should be simple enough. You just need to tweak it to use A+B=C and allow for bounding C, which will probably require use of two points instead of 1 for C, a lower bound index and an upper bound index.

You'll probably have to do it for both arrays then check if the triple (i,j,k) is valid for both arrays afterwords, as you likely won't be able to do both arrays simultaneously.